# Install LDAP on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, login, lightdm, ldap

I'm trying to configure OpenLDAP on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and Clients (Ubuntu 14.04 and/or Linux Mint 17). It works with su command, ssh or in terminal but it doesn't work on login screen. Just after install, I can see LDAP users on login screen but after few minutes, only local users are available.
/var/log/auth.log give me :

```
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:50 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:51 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 sshd[968]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 sshd[968]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: PAM unable to dlopen(pam_kwallet.so): /lib/security/pam_kwallet.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: PAM adding faulty module: pam_kwallet.so
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "adminlocal"
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local - Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://192.168.0.22: Can't contact LDAP server
Feb 17 21:33:52 PC1 sh: nss_ldap: could not search LDAP server - Server is unavailable
Feb 17 21:33:54 PC1 dbus[431]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.42" (uid=0 pid=1518 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(un$
Feb 17 21:34:04 PC1 dbus[431]: [system] Rejected send message, 7 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.42" (uid=0 pid=1518 comm="/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground") interface="(un$
Feb 17 21:34:18 PC1 sshd[1728]: Accepted password for adminlocal from 192.168.0.53 port 61914 ssh2
Feb 17 21:34:18 PC1 sshd[1728]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user adminlocal by (uid=0)
Feb 17 21:34:44 PC1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=adminlocal uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=adminlocal rhost=  user=adminlocal
Feb 17 21:34:49 PC1 sudo: adminlocal : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/adminlocal ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /var/log/nscd.log
Feb 17 21:34:49 PC1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by adminlocal(uid=0)
Feb 17 21:34:51 PC1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Getent passwd show me ldap users so I think this is a lightdm issue...
I tried several guides, without success.
Is there anybody in the same situation ? What can I do ?
Thank you very much.
Florent

---

### Step to reproduce

Fix static IP :

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
[…]
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.22
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
gateway 192.168.0.254
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Install LDAP

```
sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd
```

No

example.com

Example Company

password x2

HDB, No, Yes, No (Default values)

Install phpldapadmin (tried with ldif files too)

```
sudo apt-get install phpldapadmin


sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
[line 161]
$config->custom->appearance['hide_template_warning'] = true;
[...]
$servers->setValue('server','host','192.168.0.22');
[...]
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=aldarim,dc=local'));
[...]
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=aldarim,dc=local');


sudo nano /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php 
[Line 2469]
$default = $this->getServer()->getValue('appearance','password_hash_custom');
```

Configure LDAP

http://192.168.0.22/phpldapadmin

- Make 2 Generic : Organisational Unit => Groups & People
- Under Groups, make 2 Posix Group => admin & employees
- Under People, make users

Install ldap client on server

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-ldap nscd
```

ldap://127.0.0.1

dc=example,dc=com

3, Yes, No (Default values)

cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

admin password

```
nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
[...]
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
[...]

sudo reboot
```

Client configuration

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-ldap nscd
```

ldap://192.168.0.22

dc=example,dc=com

3, Yes, No (Default values)

cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

admin password

```
nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
[...]
passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
[...]

sudo reboot
```

Alternative client configuration :

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-ldap ldap-auth-config
sudo auth-client-config -t nss -p lac_ldap
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Same errors...

Comment: Try using `libpam-ldapd` and `nslcd`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but... same result :'( (on a fresh install). getent passwd works but "could not connect to any LDAP server" still in /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in differences with your configuration. The dc has to match the domain `example.com` but in phpldapadmin you configured the dc as `aldarim.local`. Here are your settings:

**LDAP Config:**

- No
- example.com
- Example Company
- password x2
- HDB, No, Yes, No (Default values)

and phpldapadmin config:

```
sudo nano /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
[line 161]
$config->custom->appearance['hide_template_warning'] = true;
[...]
$servers->setValue('server','host','192.168.0.22');
[...]
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=aldarim,dc=local'));
[...]
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=aldarim,dc=local');
```

Here is an example of how the domain should match, even if you use the IP address: See [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) which gives you the idea that you can enter anything you want, but the two settings MUST match.

Change your LDAP config to use `aldarim.local` and call the company aldarim and you should be ok. Or change the following lines to use `example.com`

```
$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=example,dc=com'));
[...]
$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com');
```

In any case, they have to match.