# LDAP errors before network is up

Tags: boot, networking, 15.04, ldap

I'm getting the following kind of errors during the boot process:

```
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as (null) - Can't contact LDAP server
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap: Can't contact LDAP server
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as (null) - Can't contact LDAP server
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: failed to bind to LDAP server ldap://ldap: Can't contact LDAP server
May 11 12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server (sleeping 1 seconds)...
```

This happens before the network is up, when the ldap server is obviously unreachable.
Once the network is up ldap authentication works properly.

The point is that the boot process shouldn't need to retrieve any user or group from the ldap server.

/etc/nsswitch.conf is configured as follows:

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap

hosts:          files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Note that the same setup didn't cause any errors with Ubuntu 14.10.

How do I find out what is trying to connect to the ldap and why?

**Update**

`journalctl -o verbose _PID=482` returns

```
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _SYSTEMD_SLICE=system.slice
    PRIORITY=3
    _CAP_EFFECTIVE=3fffffffff
    _EXE=/bin/dash
    _SYSTEMD_CGROUP=/system.slice/networking.service
    _SYSTEMD_UNIT=networking.service
    _TRANSPORT=syslog
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=sh
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=10
    MESSAGE=nss_ldap: could not connect to any LDAP server as (null) - Can't contact LDAP server
    _PID=484
    _COMM=resolvconf
    _CMDLINE=/bin/sh /sbin/resolvconf -a lo.inet
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1431438028207234
```

I still struggle to understand what's happening.
The networking.service unit doesn't seem to actually contain anything, so I don't know how it is related to resolvconf. I also can't figure out why resolvconf is using the ldap address.

Comment: Although it is possible to see this error with version 14, as the person at http://askubuntu.com/questions/587068/ attests.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find out what is trying to connect to the ldap and why?

You look at the log, and see it saying:

```
12:19:25 vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64 sh[482]: nss_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
```

You think:

> "Aha!  Process ID 482."

And then you run

```
journalctl -o verbose _PID=482
```

and possibly

```
journalctl -o verbose SYSLOG_PID=482
```

and look at the log some more, to see exactly what program "sh" is, what command line it was passed, and what user was running it.

Comment: This is really helpful, and not only to solve this issue (I woudl upvote if I could). I didn't know I could get such detailed information out of journalctl.